# User Page is not responsive as width of screen decreases

Tags: bug, profile-page, design

Recently, I came to my user page to check how things were doing and I resized my tab to around 1260 pixels. Around this width, elements on the page became fixed and would no longer move relative to the size of my window.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC9rX.jpg

As the giant screenshot displays, a lot of the elements are shoved off the right of the screen. Allowing me to use my muscles to scroll sideways. A muscle I have not yet trained.

Now obviously this gets worse the more I shrink the width:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3s3E.jpg

Now I've got to **really** scroll sideways.
What's up here? I've never seen a website make me scroll sideways besides apple.com.

I'm using

- Chrome: 92.0.4515.131
- [macOS v11.5.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur)

Comment: Yes, that's right, the user profiles are not and never have been responsive (they're being worked on currently)

Comment: For reference: [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) and [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)